# mysql - how to include zeros in the count in only one single query

Tags: mysql

I only have one table to count, I am not using any join. Is this possible?

`Select engagement_type as name, COUNT(engagement_type) as y
 From events
 group By engagement_type
 order By  engagement_type`

But only result is 1 row with count per engagement_type. I want to show all count of accounts without any engagement_type. Like these:

[image]

Will appreciate your answers! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a lookup table where all possible values of `engagement_type` are stored?

Comment: Using `as name` may not be a good idea in your case, trying removing it

Comment: regardles of the alias, no there are no other tables. only one

Comment: Can you show further details of the table you are querying & your expected results. Where do all the different Engagement Types come from?

Comment: A `SELECT` can only return values that are in the table. If they're not (and that would be the only way to get a zero), how should the database know that, say, "Old" is a valid EngagementType? There are also likely to be zero records for EngagementType=42 and just as many for EngagementType="fhgfhg$%$KHFHGFDWEXZ<" -- which of those do you want in your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a lookup-table, say `EngagementTypes`, where all possible values of engagement types are stored, then you can query this table to get the full list of all types and do a `LEFT JOIN` to `events` table in order to get the corresponding count:

```
Select t1.engagement_type as name, COUNT(t2.engagement_type) as y
From EngagementTypes AS t1
left join events as t2 on t1.engagement_type = t2.engagement_type
group By t1.engagement_type
order By t1.engagement_type
```

Comment: no there is none :(. struggling with only one table

Comment: The info about the `engagement_type` has to be stored somewhere, so that you will be somehow able to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks!, I created another table for it. that solved my problem